# Download currently playing audio using java

Tags: java, audio, input, download

I want to parse webpage to find all the mp3 files, that can be played, and then start them one by one and download. The problem is how to get url of the currently playing sound? Are there any tools for such things in java?

Comment: so basically, you want to visit a warez site, and in one click or less download all (copyright protected) songs?
tried anything so far

Comment: No, i don`t want to download copyright protected songs. I want to use it just for one website, where all materials are not protected for copying and sharing. However download links to the mp3s i want to download are broken(site is rather old). I know how to get an url of currently playing mp3 through the browser and download it, but it is really slow way for a big amount of files i need. 
The question is how to get url of these mp3 through java?

Comment: "where all materials are not protected for copying and sharing" .. just because the person who made that site didn't protect the stuff he puts on it, doesn't mean it's not copyright protected. Copyright protection is a legal matter, not a technical one.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the websites want to allow you to download mp3 files from them. The files are on their web servers and the HTML files may contain the name of those files, but they don't give you access to the mp3 files themselves. If you want to "get" the audio from a website, you'll have to use a third party program or plugin that can "pull" the audio from a video or audio player.

Comment: I got a direct link to a mp3 on server using chrome webpage code viewer
http://imgur.com/x2ES3wo
That means it is possible. The question is how to do the same, using java?

Comment: I think that doing it with Java code might be a little bit more difficult than doing it with a third party extension for Google Chrome or maybe with a program designed for that purpose. Doing it in Java would require you to play a stream and record the stream as it's being played. The stream would be in a format that is compressed, but the recording process produces un-compressed audio. If you've ever used Audacity, the recording process typically produces .wav files at first. If you make a .wav file from a .mp3 stream and then re-compress it, quality goes down.

Comment: I realised that i should parse webpage and find all audiocontainers, which include a full path to the file on server, without extension, like: "http://thesiteineed.org/archive/filesineed/2001_08_04_000203". Then i have to just write all the paths one by one to the string, add an extension to them and download.

Comment: Oh. I thought you were using SoundCloud or something like that. If you have the actual URL of the mp3 file itself, that should work.

Comment: No, as i said, it just an old site with broken download urls :)